# How to access contents of .gz file avaiblable on external FTP server in Python

Tags: python, ftp, gzip

```
import json
import gzip
import linecache

cnt = 0
jsonfile = 'refsnp_blobs.json.gz'

........
....

fin = gzip.open(jsonfile,'r')  
fin.seek(100, 0)                  #go to random position
print(fin.readline())
exit()
```

refsnp_blobs.json.gz is available on external FTP server, I don't want to download since its more the 50 gb.
If there is any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access contents of an archive file stored on a remote FTP server without actually downloading the file.

Of course, you can extract the contents while downloading on-the-fly, without actually storing the archive file locally (as suggested by @Cheney in a comment). This way, you spare a local storage, but you will still waste a bandwidth.

---

If you have a shell access to the server, you can extract the file remotely and access only the part of the extracted contents you are after.

---

For a similar question, see [Download zip file via FTP and extract files in memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14527010/850848).