# How to create a zip archive in Python without creating files on file system?

Tags: python, zip, archive

One easy way is to create a directory and populate it with files.  Then archive and compress that directory into a zip file called, say, `file.zip`.  But this approach is needless since my files are in memory already, and needing to save them to disk is excessive.

Is it possible that I create the directory structure right in memory, without saving the unzipped files/directories?  So that I end up saving only the final `file.zip` (without the intermediate stage of saving files/directories on file system)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463770/python-in-memory-zip-library

Comment: @S4rt-H4K I don't think it says how to add a directory structure to it.  E.g. add a folder/directory to it.  Thoughts?

Comment: do you want to add files in multiple directories?

Comment: Just 1 directory.  Or maybe multiple.  Not quite sure about their number yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html):

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("file.zip", "w") as zip_file:
    zip_file.writestr("root/file.json", json.dumps(data))
    zip_file.writestr("README.txt", "hello world")
```

Comment: This worked for me, but there is a typo: in the import `Zipfile` should be `ZipFile` (with a capital F)